# jQuery: How to disable/make exception for only one tag?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using .tooltip for a simple description of each  throughout a page. It works fantastic for everything but the title name of the page (not just icons and menus) shows up at the bottom left side of the screen. How can I make an exception for just the title tag that starts with the word "step"? Thanks.

```
$.widget( "ui.tooltip", {
version: "1.9.2",
options: {
    content: function() {
        return $( this ).attr( "title" );
    },
    hide: true,
    // Disabled elements have inconsistent behavior across browsers (#8661)
    items: "[title]:not([disabled])",
    position: {
        my: "left top+15",
        at: "left bottom",
        collision: "flipfit flip"
    },
    show: true,
    tooltipClass: null,
    track: false,

    // callbacks
    close: null,
    open: null
},
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a normal jquery selector for your `items` definition:

```
items: '[title^="step"]:not([disabled])',
```

should do the trick, for more selector fun, see the [jquery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors&redirect=no)

@edit:
I just re-read your question, to exclude the items with the word "step" at the beginning of the title, use this:

```
items: '[title]:not([disabled]):not([title^="step"])',
```

Comment: "inside your config object, where you define the selector you exclude the ones you dont want to with a 'very normal selector'" was what i meant.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style type="text/css">
/* hide the html title tag from on-screen display */
    #ui-tooltip-0 {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question (how to hide the title tag if it starts with the word 'step').

Comment: Normal selector? Like <script> 
 $(function() {
items: '[title]:not([disabled]):not([title^="Nomination-1"])'
 });  
</script> Also, instead of the word "step" can you have it use the word in the <title> tags? That's what the tooltip is picking up.